# How can I get the HTML data from a post request on the server via express?

Tags: node.js, express

HTML file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <style>
            textarea {
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
            }
        </style>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>CSV Report Generator</h1>
            <form method='POST' action='/' id='submitCSV'>
                <textarea name='csv' form='submitCSV'></textarea>
                <br>
                <input type='submit' value='Get CSV'>
            </form>
            <br>
            <div>
                <h3>CSV Response</h3>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Relevant Server Side Code

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let csvReport = parseJSON(req.body.csv);
    // res.end('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
    res.end(csvReport);
/*
    templating & html 
    file system - read file from client & insert CSV into appropriate spot -> send back to client
    readfile => 'string of all the html'
*/
})
```

Basically, I'm sending in some JSON data through my form to the server via a post request. Once I have the JSON data, I'm basically parsing it into a different format and sending that back (code not shown since it's not relevant). What I'm trying to do is somehow read the HTML that the form is contained in so I can insert it into the HTML and send that whole HTML string back as the server response. It is dumb as there's many tools to use instead but I am doing it this way because I am required to do so. How can I read the contents of my html file from which the request came from?

Comment: Are you using ajax? hbs or any front-end framework to send and manage the data?

Comment: No, I would use AJAX if possible since this would make it easy but I'm not allowed to use anything BUT html and express. Hence why I'm asking such a weird question